# python raspberry pi global variables and gpio

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I have a python script on my raspberry pi where i've declared variables like below:

```
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(26,GPIO.OUT)

display = lcd_drivers.Lcd()

app_path = '/home/pi/MyApp'

API_ENDPOINT = 'https://localhost/api'
API_KEY = "XXXXYYY"
```

And then I have multiple functions that call these variables for example:

```
def processTag(tag):

    r = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT)
    rd = r.json()

    display.lcd_clear()
    display.lcd_display_string(rd['name'], 1)

    GPIO.output(26,GPIO.HIGH)
```

Above is one example function, there are other functions too that refer to the variables.

It seems to be working  perfectly. However, i'm wondering do I need to define all of those outside variables inside every function using the global prefix, for example like below. If needed then that would mean declaring them as global repeatedly for all functions which seems like an overkill.

```
def processTag(tag):

    global API_ENDPOINT
    global API_KEY
    global display
    global GPIO
    global app_path

    r = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT)
    rd = r.json()

    display.lcd_clear()
    display.lcd_display_string(rd['name'], 1)

    GPIO.output(26,GPIO.HIGH)
```

Comment: You can simply access a variable from a higher namespaces. The `global` keyword is required if you want to *replace* or *create* a variable in the global namespace.

Comment: Pythonic way is to define a class (or classes) for that. Then pass the instance of that class through the code here and there. It's called object-oriented programming.